# Where to see the complete list of juju charms available?

Tags: juju

that sounds like such a basic question to ask, but I can't seem to find a good answer.

**Where to see the complete list of juju charms available?**

Except for the official 'Juju Charms Store' website which is, in my opinion, totally unusable (and search doesn't work for me), I can't seem to find anything.

I would like to have something like NPM repository search where I can see all packages available and search through them in a convenient way.

For now all that I can see are:

- [Juju Charms Store](https://jujucharms.com/) (and search doesn't work for me)
- [A mirror of Charms on GitHub](https://github.com/charms) (but I can't seem to find out how good, accurate, recent is the list, 'nginx' charm isn't in the list for example, which is odd)

Comment: maybe clear your browser cookies first; then, go to https://jujucharms.com/ and, before you do anything else, refresh your browser to get rid of that annoying introduction popup that won't let you use the website

Comment: Yes it kinda worked. Enough for me to see some packages. But this page is really annoying. Would happily welcome any other source :)

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could file a bug about the jujucharms.com search not working: https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-gui please be as specific as possible including steps to reproduce the issue you're experiencing, browser, os, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: The new location to view all charms is https://charmhub.io

---

Because the search is not working for you, you can find a list of the promoted charms here: http://manage.jujucharms.com/charms

There is also a massive list of all of the charms on launchpad here: https://code.launchpad.net/charms

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. Not perfect but will do the trick.

Comment: First link is now broken.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the reply.